# Is every group a nontrivial subgroup of a larger group?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $\kappa$ be a cardinal number strictly bigger than $|G|$.

> **(1)** Is there a group $H$ for which $G$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $H$?
>
> **(2)** Is there a group $H$ for which $G$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $H$ and $ \ |H|= \kappa \ $?

---

Let $ \ \mu: H \times H \to H \ $ be the binary operation of the group $H$. That is, $(H, \mu)$ is the group. I say that a group $(J, \nu)$ is a subgroup of $(H, \mu)$ if, and only if,

**(i)** $ \quad J \subset H \ $;

**(ii)** $ \quad \mu|_{J \times J} = \nu \ $.

Here I can only use ZFC set theory. That is, equality is "set theory equality" and identifications or isomorphisms are strictly prohibited.

---

This question appeared because in a semigroup $S$ without identity it is very easy to add an extra element (set) $ \ e \notin S \ $ such that $ \ S \cup \{ e \} \ $ is a semigroup with identity $e$, just defining by hand what the operation do on it. I wonder if this is possible with other elements and other structures as well.

Comment: Just take the direct product of $G$ with any group of cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: I'm not an expert in ZFC, but it seems to me that given an injective function $f:A\to B$, you can always define $B'=(B\setminus f(A))\sqcup A$ and $f':A\to B'$ as the inclusion. Then you have a bijection $\theta:B\to B'$ such that $\theta \circ f=f'$. So any solution "up to isomorphism" can be turned into a "strict" solution.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you mean that the underlying set of the direct product is the cartesian product $ \ G \times H \ $? How do you construct this cartesian product in a way that $ \ G \subset G \times H \ $?

Comment: @ArnaudD. How do you define $ \ X \sqcup Y \ $?

Comment: Coincidentally, just yesterday I was reading about the construction that takes a ring (which may not have an identity) and extends it to a ring with identity. The construction is similar to the one that turns a semigroup into a monoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you know that the answer work "up to isomorphism", then the answer is positive in the set theoretic sense as well.

Suppose that $(H,*_H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(G',*_{G'})$. Namely, there is a monomorphism $\varphi\colon H\to G'$. Let $G$ be the set $H\cup(\{H\}\times(G'\setminus\operatorname{range}(\varphi)))$. We can replace $\{H\}$ by $\{x\}$ for which $H\cap\{x\}\times G'=\varnothing$, and of course there is a proper class of such $x$'s.

Now define $\Phi\colon G\to G'$ as follows:
$$\Phi(x)=\begin{cases}\varphi(x) & x\in H\\ y & x=(H,y)\end{cases},$$
namely either $\varphi(x)$ or the projection onto $G'$. And define $$x*_Gy=\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(x)*_{G'}\Phi(y)).$$

It is not hard to check that $(G,*)$ is a group and that $H$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$. Of course, there are no restrictions on the cardinality of $G$.

Comment: Note that this requires that $G'$ is disjoint from $H$, but that is of course easy to arrange. If it isn't, then first replace $G'$ by $G'\times\{H\}$, for example.

Comment: Right. Thanks. That's a good point.

Comment: This is great answer. Thanks.